# Google Apps Script get current month from Date()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a function to generate data according to a start and an end date.

While I was testing my functions I've realized some wrong calculated values.

Long story short the `getMonth()` method for `Date` objects is returning a unexpected value.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getMonth());
var date2 = new Date(2014, 1, 1);
console.log(date2);
```

Can someone explain to me the reason why to start a month at 0, even if it's not possible to create a right `Date` object using that index.

Even though `date2` my second example is from the [official docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) of JS and is returning a unexpected value according to the example giving in the "Parameters" section.

Comment: JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11.

Comment: Yes, I totally understand that and it could be a better way to calculate with those `Date` objects, but it doesn't answer the question about my created object `date2`, which should be (according to the official docs) `"2014-02-01"`

Comment: When I run `console.log(date2)` in my Chrome I get: `Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)` So it behaves the way you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, looks like I forgot about the TZ.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Airwavezx mentioned the code was correct.

> tl;tr I forgot to use timezones and JS is counting months from 0

So a solution to my question could be:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getMonth()+1);
var date2 = new Date("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z");
console.log(date2);
```